# Can I say a single variable with a high factor loading in an exploratory factor analysis is an additional factor?

Tags: interpretation, factor-analysis

I'm doing a exploratory factor analysis for an investigator who wants to find factors from 7 variables. I did a preliminary analysis and found two main factors, each have 3 variables with loading > 0.6. There's one variable left alone for itself as a factor with loading >0.99. Should I report it as one factor or just leave it out and do another factor analysis? I heard a factor should include at least 3 variables.

Comment: Thanks. It is mainly ordinal data for rating subjects at 0-5 scale of 60 subjects. The investigator wants for find if some variables can be grouped into new latent variables to reduce the data dimension, or create new rating system with fewer variables. If we found two latent variables from the 7 variables with three variables each, but the one left can not be fit in any latent variables and left alone, what should I do with it?

Comment: @subhashc.davar  [1] 3.84061146 1.24878467 0.76900877 0.57878187 0.25571698 0.22084958 0.08624668. lt suggests two factors but I'm not sure if I should just ignore the third one.

Comment: @subhashc.davar Haven't assigned the names, just call factor 1 & 2

Comment: If you are going to calculate sum scores from your variables which is wat people often do then there is no difference between treating the loner as a factor or a variable.

Comment: @mdewey could you please explain a little more about calculating sum scores? The goal is to explain that in this study, these seven variables could be explained by 2-3 fewer factors. It's something like that factor 1 is strongly correlated with var. 1,2,3 , factor 2 is correlated with var. 4,5,6, while var. 7 is a loner factor which is independent from any other variables/factors?

Comment: @subhashc.davar if I did that without the loner variable, and the result yield the same two factors with 3 variables each, how to interpret the analysis? Do I need to mention that there's another variable excluded because it's not correlated with other variables?

Comment: It was a question, is computing sum scores what you really wanted to do?

Comment: @mdewey No it's not. I only want to find if the 7 variables can be grouped into several domains. One variable as a domain is not what we want and just wonder if it can be ignored in the factor analysis

Comment: @Joe Have you computed the values ? is there any change in Factor loadings or eigenvalues.  ?

Comment: I did not understand the question. _How many factors did you model (extract)_? 2 or 3 or how? Were you doing EFA or doing PCA?

Comment: @ttnphns I used 7 variables for EFA and kept 3 factors that explained 0.76 of the variance. The first two factors have 3 variables each and explained only 0.58 of the variance. The third one has only 1 variable that has a loading of 0.99 (cutoff =0.4). My question is can I explain the third one as a factor (contains only one variable )?

Comment: @subhashc.davar The previous cumulative variance of the three factors are 0.316, 0.577 and 0.759. In factor 3, var. 7 is the only variable with significant loading 0.99, others are <0.4. I excluded the single variable (var. 7) in factor 3 and did another EFA with 6 variables (var.1 -6). All loading values changed. var. 2 is in factor 3 alone (loading=0.84, others <.3 in factor 3). The cumulative variance are  0.335   0.563   0.721. I feel that I should keep 3 factors as the cumulative variance is too low with 2 factors. The question now is how to interpret factor 3 (single var.)?

Comment: @subhashc.davar ordinal variables to describe patient's disease status. Assuming they are evenly distributed. These 7 variables describe different but correlated symptoms.

Comment: @subhashc.davar ` Test of the hypothesis that 2 factors are sufficient.
The chi square statistic is 22.19 on 8 degrees of freedom.
The p-value is 0.00457`, `Test of the hypothesis that 3 factors are sufficient.
The chi square statistic is 5.84 on 3 degrees of freedom.
The p-value is 0.12` . Looks like 3 factor is necessary.

Comment: @subhashc.davar scale

Comment: @subhashc.davar  Subject were asked to give a score for 7 questions about their symptom after radiation treatment. These questions describe correlated symptoms and the scores reflect the severity. Total 60 patients and 7 variables with scores 0-5.

Answer (score 1):

@Joe Question-1 : You can not consider a single variable/ question item as a factor. The factor  should have at least two variables / question items.  Question2 YOU may  undertake another EFA without this variable (however do justify). YOU have already done that and now you find factor -3 with var.2 + a few others as an alternative to erstwhile factor.  That is  the real purpose of EFA. Factor 3  (new one) is a valid factor as long as you can justify its contribution to dependant variable. Question 3 -  number of variables in a factor depends on accuracy of data , descriptive  or experimenta design etc. It is an issue that requires ingenuity and statistical acumen. best  wishes!

If you  can justify in theory that two factors are adequate to explain  the specified phenomenon, you can exclude  variable 3. The  third variable could be a confounding factor . And you can justify its exclusion saying that in net terms, there is no effect . Three or more " variables"  Ifor a factor  '  seems absurd  without evidence.